# How to ignore xsi:nil attributes when parsing xml with XmlSlurper

Tags: java, groovy

We're upgrading a 3rd-party product from which we consume XML content. The new version generates XML with `xsi:nil="true"` attributes, indicating null elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <cusip  xsi:nil="true"/>
  <ticker xsi:nil="true"/>
  <year>2014</year>
</data>
```

When parsing, we use:

```
def parsed = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
...
element.attributes().each{ k,v -> {
}
```

..but the attribute key for `xsi:nil="true"`, comes back as:

`"{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil"`

...and this is raising hell with our downstream processing because it's not expecting an attribute key enclosed in braces.

Does XmlSlurper support a way to ignore `xsi` schema type attributes without having to filter them out manually?

**TO BE CLEAR**

Given the xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <cusip  xsi:nil="true"/>
  <ticker xsi:nil="true"/>
  <year format='yyyy'>2014</year>
</data>
```

...only attribute `format` is visible; `xsi:nil` attributes are ignored:

```
def parser1 = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(xml)
assert parser1.children()*.attributes().size() == 1   // for 'format'
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

You can use XmlSlurper with namespaceAware set to false as:

```
def parsed = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(xml)
```

you can also use [**XmlParser**](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html) for parsing, similar to XmlSlurper, if feasible. You have the option of making the parser namespace unaware by using as below:

```
def parsed = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(xml)
```

Toggle the second argument (`namespaceAware`) of the constructor to `true` to see the difference.

Example:

```
def xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <cusip  xsi:nil="true"/>
  <ticker xsi:nil="true"/>
  <year>2014</year>
</data>
'''

def parser1 = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(xml)
def parser2 = new XmlParser(false, true).parseText(xml)

println parser1.children()*.attributes()
println parser2.children()*.attributes()
```

Comment: But XmlSlurper  has similar construtor with namespaceunaware argument, what's the difference?

Comment: No difference, you can use that as well. Updating accordingly.

Comment: It won't disable attributes but suppresses evaluating the namespaces.

Comment: @raffian Exact test works fine for me. [Run this script](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/3225001).

Comment: Your test is for 3 attributes; I only want to see 1 returned while the xsi:nils are ignored.

Comment: Those attributes can be ignored easily from the list of attributes, I do not understand where the problem lies in using that . :)

Comment: You can try using `parser1.children()*.attributes().findAll { !('xsi:nil' in it.keySet() ) }`

Comment: The problem with filtering manually is just that; it's manual; I'd rather the parser do it via configuration; that was my original request, but thanks for your insight, +1 on GroovyWebConsole!